# How to COUNT and SELECT with WHERE in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `user` and `group` and also a `usergroup` as a link table which contains which users exist in a group.

`user` table

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | name  |
+-----+-------+
| U12 | John  |
| U13 | Rick  |
| U14 | Morty |
| U15 | Alex  |
| U16 | Felix |
+-----+-------+
```

`group` table

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| id  |  name  | points |
+-----+--------+--------+
| G12 | Red    |     11 |
| G13 | Blue   |     22 |
| G14 | Green  |     55 |
| G15 | Yellow |     64 |
| G16 | Orange |     23 |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

`usergroup` table

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | group_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | U12     | G12      |
|  2 | U14     | G12      |
|  3 | U15     | G12      |
|  4 | U15     | G15      |
|  5 | U12     | G13      |
+----+---------+----------+
```

To select the groups that a particular user is in, I can just do

```
SELECT group.*
FROM usergroup 
INNER JOIN group 
ON group.id = usergroup.group_id 
WHERE usergroup.user_id = ?
```

But how to also simultaneously select the number of **total users** in the same group?

Expected Sample Output - for the groups that user `U12` is in, along with total user count

```
+-----+------+--------+-------------+
| id  | name | points | users_count |
+-----+------+--------+-------------+
| G12 | Red  |     11 |           3 |
| G13 | Blue |     22 |           1 |
+-----+------+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT y.id, y.name, y.points, y.users_count
FROM usergroup x INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT b.id, b.name, b.points, count(a.user_id) as users_count
    FROM usergroup a INNER JOIN group b
    ON a.group_id = b.id
    GROUP BY b.id ) AS y
ON x.group_id = y.id
WHERE x.user_id = 'U12'
```

Answer (score 1):

use scalar subquery

```
SELECT `group`.* , (select count(id) from usergroup a where a.group_id=usergroup.group_id ) as user_count
FROM usergroup 
INNER JOIN `group` ON `group`.id = usergroup.group_id 
WHERE usergroup.user_id = 'U12'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT a.group_id,
       a.NAME,
       a.points,
       c.user_count
FROM   group a,
       usergroup b,
       (SELECT x.group_id,
               Count(*) AS user_count
        FROM   usergroup x
        GROUP  BY x.group_id) c
WHERE  a.group_id = b.group_id
       AND a.group_id = c.group_id
       AND user_id = 'U12';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT group.*, count(usergroup.group_id),usergroup.user_id
FROM usergroup 
INNER JOIN group 
ON group.id = usergroup.id 
GROUP BY usergroup.group_id
Having usergroup.user_id = 'U12'
```

You need to use group by with having.
Check it on SQLFiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b63e13/3/0

Comment: Read the question , OP wants to get count while passing the user-id. Grouping will not give the desired result.

Comment: did you test your sql? there are tons of errors, such as the having cause